# Absolute center text but left aligned

Tags: html, css

I am creating a hero image style banner where I want to center text in the middle of an image, but have the rows of the text be left aligned.

I have a `p` which contains two lines of content, separated by a `br`. I want the width of the line to be the width of the largest amount of content and also for this line to be centered. The next line should then be text aligned left.

This js fiddle shows what I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/hnox2t18/

AS you can see, the `p` doesn't always stretch to be the width of the content, instead splitting the first line up. The `p` should be the width of the content up to the `br`, and centered at this width.

CSS

```
.home-slider .home-slide {
  position: relative;
}
.home-slider img {
  width: 100%;
}
.home-slider p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-family: "proxima-nova", Arial, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #ffffff;
  line-height: 1em;
}
.home-slider span {
  font-weight: bolder;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="home-slider">
    <div class="home-slide">
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=0&w=800&h=400">
        <p>Over <span>1,500</span> ports, <span>3000</span> terminals<br />and      <span>6,800</span> berths</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you use flexbox?

Comment: We need to support older browsers unfortunately so are trying to stay away from flexbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `white-space:nowrap;` on the `p` tag.

[**JSFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/hnox2t18/4/)

```
 p {

    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-family: "proxima-nova", Arial, sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #ffffff;
    line-height: 1em;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Adjust as required in media queries.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an enclosing div that will be centered and include your p inside.

CSS

```
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

p {
    font-family: "proxima-nova", Arial, sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #ffffff;
    line-height: 1em;
}
```

HTML

```
...    
<div class="overlay"><p>Over <span>1,500</span> ports, <span>3000</span> terminals<br />and <span>6,800</span> berths</p></div>
...
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e4tqcs49/

Comment: If you shrink down the window size you will see that the text drops onto 3 lines, despite there being space for the words to fit on two still. Ideally I want it to stay on two until it is changed with media queries.

Comment: Add a width to the p?

Comment: The p needs to create it's own width so that it will be centered horizontally

Comment: Exactly like that! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the split up before the line Break happens, because your p isn't big enough.

you should set a width property to make your p big enough to fit. 725px should work with your font size. if its smaller the first line breaks.
But this solution isn't responsive.

```
.home-slider p {
   width: 725px;
```

Eventually you have to adjust the font-size too.

Answer (score 0):

I use "reset css" functions ;) :

```
* {
  margin: 0;
}
```

`<p>` tags have margins